# Authenticating Username and Password in nodejs with mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am creating a login page and need to authenticate user's username and password whenever he logs in. My Database is mongodb and i am using expressjs in nodejs. Signup functionality is working well and i am able to sign up users but Log In functionality is not working. Kindly help me with knowledge of MongoDB to authenticate users and store their cookies.

Here's my server code..

```
//------------modules used-------------//
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const helmet = require("helmet");
const cookieparser = require("cookie-parser");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
//------------modules used-------------//

const app = express();
app.use(helmet());
// allow the app to use cookieparser
app.use(cookieparser());
// allow the express server to process POST request rendered by the ejs files 
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

//-------------------mongodb-----------------//
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/loginDB", { useNewUrlParser: true });
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: String,
    pass: String,
})
const User = new mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
//-------------------mongodb-----------------//

app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"));

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    // check if user is logged in, by checking cookie
    let username = req.cookies.username;
    if(username){
        return res.render("mainpage", {
            username,
        });
    }else{
        res.redirect("/login");
    }

});
app.get("/mainpage", (req, res) => {
    // check if user is logged in, by checking cookie
    let username = req.cookies.username;
    if(username){
        return res.render("mainpage", {
            username,
        });
    }else{
        res.redirect("/login");
    }

});
app.get("/register", (req, res) => {

    return res.render("signup");

});

app.get("/login", (req, res) => {
    // check if there is a msg query
    let bad_auth = req.query.msg ? true : false;

    // if there exists, send the error.
    if (bad_auth) {
        return res.render("login", {
            error: "Invalid username or password",
        });
    } else {
        // else just render the login
        return res.render("login");
    }
});

app.post("/login", (req, res) => {
    // get the data
    let { username, password } = req.body;

    User.find({email: username},(err)=>{
        if(err){
            res.redirect("/");
        }else{
            res.cookie("username", username, {
                maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
                secure: true,
                httpOnly: true,
                sameSite: 'lax'
            });
            res.redirect("/mainpage");
        }
    })

    // fake test data
    // let userdetails = {
    //     username: "Bob",
    //     password: "123456",
    // };

    // // basic check
    // if (
    //     username === userdetails["username"] &&
    //     password === userdetails["password"]
    // ) {
    //     // saving the data to the cookies
    //     res.cookie("username", username, {
    //         maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
    //         secure: true,
    //         httpOnly: true,
    //         sameSite: 'lax'
    //     });
    //     // redirect

    //     return res.redirect("/");

    // } else {
    //     // redirect with a fail msg
    //     return res.redirect("/login?msg=fail");
    // }
});

app.post("/register",(req,res)=>{
    let { given_username, given_password } = req.body;

    const newUser = new User({
        email: given_username,
        pass: given_password,
    });

    newUser.save((err)=>{
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }else{
            console.log('saved');
        }
    })

    res.cookie("username", given_username, {
        maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
        secure: true,
        httpOnly: true,
        sameSite: 'lax'
    });
    
    res.redirect("/")
})

app.get("/logout", (req, res) => {
    // clear the cookie
    res.clearCookie("username");
    // redirect to login
    return res.redirect("/login");
});



app.listen('3000', () => console.log(`server started`));
```

Comment: Saving a plain password in DB is an awful idea. You need to save the hash of this password only instead of the password itself. And then on `login` route you should compare the hash previously saved in DB with the one calculated from the passed password.

Comment: I can do that, please tell me how to compare the passwords in login route

Comment: You should calculate a hash of a password the same way you do when you save the hash on sign-up

Comment: Hi Anatoly, You are right but what is the code to do so.. Currently in my code `app.post("/login", (req, res) => {
    let { username, password } = req.body;

    User.find({email: username},(err)=>{
        if(err){
            res.redirect("/login");
        }else{
            //console.log(email);
            res.cookie("username", username, {
                maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
                secure: true,
                httpOnly: true,
                sameSite: 'lax'
            });
            res.redirect("/mainpage");
        }
    })`

Comment: ..even if the email does not exists it never goes to err, should i use different method then the user.find, or should i rectify my code somehow

Comment: i can use md5 for hashing but "where should i add the if else statement for password comparison" is it inside the User.find statement or outside it ?

Comment: Kindly help bro i am stuck in this for very very long time and i am on the verge of giving up Javascript altogether

Comment: You need to check a hash of password with a hash of found user in `else` of course. You need to indciate the second parameter in order to get access to found users. And it would be better to use `findOne` instead of `find` if oyu realyy can have only one user with a given email

Comment: According to your code if a user is not found you will execute `res.redirect("/");`. Isn't it correct? Did you check what branch of `if` is executed in this case to make sure all goes right?

Comment: Hi Anatoly, this is my code now

Comment: `app.post("/login", (req, res) => {
    // get the data
    const name = req.body.login_username;
    const pass = req.body.login_password;

    let a = User.findOne({email: name}).exec();
    if(a){
        console.log('found');
        // let b = a.pass;
        // console.log(b);
        res.redirect("/")
    }else{
        console.log('not f');
    }

});`

Comment: even if there is no user in database with the same email it STILL shows as user found.

Comment: Shouldn't `let a = User.findOne({email: name}).exec(); ` be `let a = await User.findOne({email: name}).exec(); ` ?

Comment: thanks bro.. Love uh a lot it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code for login API

```js
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs")

app.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
  let { username, password } = req.body;
  const user = await User.findOne({ email: username }).lean()
  if (!user) {
    res.status(404).send({message: "No  User Found"})
  } else {

    var validatePassword = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)

    if (!validatePassword) {
      res.status(400).send({message: "Invalid Password"})
    } else {
      res.cookie("username", username, {
        maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
        secure: true,
        httpOnly: true,
        sameSite: 'lax'
    });
      res.redirect("/mainpage");
  
    }
  }
```